# get path name of my drive using google stream

Tags: r, google-drive-api, pathname

I just updated my Google Drive to Google Stream. How can I find the path name of My Drive, e.g. when programming in R? At work, I use a PC and copied the folder to Documents. At home, I use a mac and would like to avoid creating a duplicate folder.

I tried source("file.R") and some other functions, and different path names but so far am stumped. Thanks for your help. Note: I'm not sure if the tag is correct- I couldn't add a tag for google stream.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out: right click, option, copy pathname. Hooray!

http://osxdaily.com/2015/11/05/copy-file-path-name-text-mac-os-x-finder/